# JQ Error: Cannot iterate over string while trying to map IP and Ports

Tags: json, jq

I have a below json output, I would love to remove duplicate data and map the data in a table format using jq. I am using the below query but I keep getting an error;

> Cannot iterate over string ("78.45.196...)

e.t.c.

**Json data**

```json
[
  {
    "ip": "78.45.196.23",
    "timestamp": "1616566245",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 5060,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ip": "67.89.378.82",
    "timestamp": "1616566255",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 2000,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ip": "67.89.378.82",
    "timestamp": "1616566255",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 2080,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ip": "78.45.196.23",
    "timestamp": "1616566245",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 5060,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ip": "67.89.378.82",
    "timestamp": "1616566255",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 2000,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ip": "78.45.196.23",
    "timestamp": "1616566245",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 5080,
        "proto": "tcp",
        "status": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "ttl": 50
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**My query**

```sh
jq -r '.[][] | group_by(.ip) | map({ip: .ip, ports: map(.ports[].port) | add | unique})' jsonfile.json
```

**Expected output**

- To remove duplicates and get ip and ports.
- Or can one explain to me how to get unique values from both IP and ports.

```json
[
    {"ip:" "67.89.378.82", "ports:"[2000, 2080]},
    {"ip:" "78.45.196.23", "ports:"[5060, 5080]}
]
```

Comment: Okay let me do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct your desired JSON immediately following the `group_by()`

```
group_by(.ip) | 
map
( 
  { 
    ip:    .[0].ip, 
    ports: [ .[].ports[].port ] | unique 
  } 
)
```

[jq play link](https://jqplay.org/s/ANvE7_uCKx)

---

Follow-up question to discard IPs that have only port as 0

```
group_by(.ip) | 
map
( 
  { 
    ip:    .[0].ip, 
    ports: [ .[].ports[] | select(.port != 0 ).port ] | unique
  } |
  select(.ports | length > 0) 
)
```